# How to search through all file in onedrive rest api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

As per documentation, we are using

GET /me/drive/search(q='{search-query}')

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_search?view=odsp-graph-online#searching-for-items-a-user-can-access

But API is returning only files under My Drive, files present in Folders which are under different user's Onedrive and shared with Me, are not returned by API.

Does someone else also facing same issue, do we have any API to search in All files and folder in share drive

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `/me/drive/` you are going to only going to get files that are yours.

You can also get files from the root organisition like this

```
/drive/root/search(q='{search-query}')
```

Comment: Thats what I thought initially, but this doesn't return any result at all. Also this is not being mentioned in API Documentation